# Bootstrap 3: Row stacking order

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 rows. I need to change the order (swap around their position) rather then using 'push and pull' technique on the columns. For example if at the desktop size you have a header div on top of a footer div when you get to the smaller tablet size it displays the footer on top of the header. is there a way to achieve this effect using jQuery/ Javascript? Hope that makes sense.

The column way I tried:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-push-12">
                <div class="well">Header</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-pull-12">
                <div class="well">Footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Trying to achieve this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row header">
        </div> <!-- I need to be on bottom at smaller viewport size -->

        <div class="row footer">
        </div> <!-- I need to be on top at smaller viewport size -->
    </div>
```

See below I am currently at the stage where I am getting responsive to work:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/E5ZkW/3/
```

If page is refreshed at < 480 it needs to stay at footer before header and once at < 480 if the window is larger then 480 it should snap back to header before footer.

thanks

Comment: It would be appreciable if you are able to provide some HTML code.What you tried ?

Comment: just curious why you are swapping your header and footer for mobile?

Comment: ...was just an easy example for demonstration purposes although yes it wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery toggleclass method, this is the link

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

you can switch between classes or remove a class from a div tag.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but I don't think this would work as what if the rows contain things inside of them. Toggle adds or removes classes/ ids but I need to move the whole row with everything inside of it. Surely this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/. Example below is without responsive but at least is the effect I am after.

html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row header">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Coffee</li>
                <li>Milk</li>
            </ul> 
        </div> <!-- Change to Bottom at smaller viewport size -->

        <div class="row footer">
            <h2>Footer</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Buns</li>
                <li>Coco Pops</li>
                <li>Coke</li>
                <li>Fanta</li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- Change to Top at smaller viewport size -->
        <div class="row toggle">
            I am the replaced div
        </div> <!-- This is used as the div to be replaced -->
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$( ".toggle" ).replaceWith( $( ".header" ) );
```